# Retrieving an array element in Scala

Tags: arrays, scala, indexing

I am calling a method that returns an array:

```
val localTrustManagerFactory =
  TrustManagerFactory.getInstance(TrustManagerFactory.getDefaultAlgorithm)
val localTrustManager =
  ((localTrustManagerFactory.getTrustManagers).apply(0)).asInstanceOf[X509TrustManager]
```

If I leave out the `.apply` call, I get a compile-time error:

```
val localTrustManager =
  ((localTrustManagerFactory.getTrustManagers)(0)).asInstanceOf[X509TrustManager]
error: too many arguments for method getTrustManagers: ()Array[javax.net.ssl.TrustManager]
```

Is there any better way to retrieve an array element? I though that the compiler would supply the `apply` method call implicitly.

**UPDATE:** The classes used in this code are from the standard Java library:

```
import javax.net.ssl.TrustManagerFactory
import javax.net.ssl.X509TrustManager
```

I don't know if the Scala compiler (2.9.2-1) interprets `getTrustManagers` as having an argument list or not.

Comment: I can't reproduce this. How is `getTrustManagers` defined and which scala version are you using? This really looks like a compiler bug.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your method getTrustManagers seems to be defined with an empty argument list, that is

```
def getTrustManagers(): Array[TrustManager]
```

rather than with no argument list

```
def getTrustManagers: Array[TrustManager]
```

What you have is a corner case, scala tries to be flexible as to dropping the empty argument list at call site, but it could be ambiguous if the apply was dropped at the same time (e.g, if there was an apply method with no argument, or if getTrustManagers was overloaded and had a version with one argument).

You can do `getTrustManagers()(0)` (same as in java, except for the (0) instead of [0].